# One UIView subclass, two different .xib files

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, uiview, xib

If I have the following files:

```
MyTableViewCell.h
MyTableViewCell.m
MyTableViewCell.xib
MyTableViewCell~ipad.xib
```

In IB, if I designate a cell as class type "MyTableViewCell", how can I get it to load from the MyTableView~ipad.xib, when on an iPad device? I tried this:

```
@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        if (IPAD) {
            self = [UIView viewWithNib:@"MyTableViewCell~ipad"];
        }
        else {
            //iphone
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is obviously wrong and leads to an infinite loop, but gives an idea of what I'm trying to do. I want MyTableViewCell~ipad.xib to be loaded for any cell that I assign as MyTableViewCell if I'm on iPad. I thought if I named it ~ipad it was supposed to work automatically, but that seems to only work on view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the cell loading in your TableView data source function. You can do it something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyTableViewCell";
    MyTableViewCell* cell = (MyTableViewCell*) ([tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier]);
    if(!cell){
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
            //iPhone
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil]; 
        }
        else{
            //iPad
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell~ipad" owner:self options:nil]; 
        }
    cell = _aCell;
    _aCell = nil;
    }
    //Continue with initialization of your UI elements
}
```

This way, the specific initialization of your cell is handled by the cell's owner class - in general, your tableViewController. It also prevents an infinite loop situation like what you posted.

For this to work, you have to add this to MyTableViewController.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyTableViewCell* aCell;
```

Also, you have to set the "File's Owner" class in your MyTableViewCell XIBs to your tableViewController Class (say MyTableViewController). Then link the UITableViewCell element in your MyTableViewCell XIBs to the `aCell` property in File's Owner.

Remember to make your TableViewController respond to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource. Also, you will have to implement the following functions for the tableViewDelegate/Datasource:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What if I'm using Static cells in the table view though?

Comment: I'm still sure that you have some IBOutlet Properties in your MyTableViewCell class (which is why you have a MyTableViewCell to begin with) that need to be set. If not, this should still work. All this code tells the iPad is - for every cell that I need to create in the table use "MyTableViewCell" for iPhones and "MyTableViewCell~iPad" for iPads.